# c# Linq for XML : tag.descendants doesn't allow to interrogate all descendents

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm fairly new on this website, it's my first question. I read the documentation, but I'm sorry in advance if I brake any code of conduct. 
Here is my question :

I have an XML file in a stream. My goal is to get the attribute "Name", "Type", and the key or keys (they've been changed for obvious reason ).

```
<YourKey>
<Product_Key Name="eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0">
<Key ID="5" Type="Static Activation Key" ClaimedDate="">BBBBB-QW36D-DPT6T-BBBB-ZZZZZ</Key>
</Product_Key>
<Product_Key Name="Windows 10 Home">
<Key ID="1251" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="1/25/2017">ZZZZZ-6GBG7-ZZZZZ-8JG23-FM47H</Key>
<Key ID="1251" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="8/23/2016">FEFEF-FVD7K-EEEEF-BEBEB-VMHX7</Key>
<Key ID="1251" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="4/28/2016">EEZZE-GYB6P-ZZZEE-R72PQ-EEEEZ</Key>
</Product_Key>
</YourKey>
```

I created a class to hold the data

```
public class MsProduct
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<string> key { get; set; }
    }
```

And I created a list of `MsProduct` to add every elements of `var list`(see after) to my object.

I created a Linq query, it compiles without the `Key = (List<string>)keys`, but I only get the value `Name, Type` is empty (I have a check if the data doesn't exists(ie == null), it replace it by " ").

When I add the `Key = (List<string>)keys`, the system throws a "System.InvalidCastException".

here is my query :

```
var productName = XDocument.Load(fileXml);
var list = from product in productName.Descendants("YourKey")
                   let name = product.Attribute("Name")
                   let type = product.Attribute("Type")
                   let keys = product.Elements("Key")
                   select new MsProduct
                   {
                       Name = (string)name,
                       Type = (string)type,
                       Key = (List<string>)keys
                   };
```

Does anyone have any idea how to query my file in order to populate my class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Type is attribute of Key and not product. Comment that line and check. One more thing, your XML is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The XML comes directly from Microsoft, it's the export of my MSDN subrscription. I didn't create the code ;). The key has been answered by the the answer just bellow, I'm now wondering how to get "type" completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keys are not strings, but `XElements`, you couldn't cast it to `string`. Depending on what do you want to get, you could do:

```
 Key = (List<string>)keys.Select(x=>x.Value).ToList()
```

or

```
 Key = (List<string>)keys.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToList()
```

But you will get nothing on your xml, because you query not products, but `YourKey`'s , to get products change first line to:

```
var list = from product in productName.Descendants("Product_Key")
```

If you want to get the type, you should consider, that you have more than one Type pro product. Either you query types to the list as keys, or you are sure they all are the same, so you could take just  the first one:

```
var list = from product in productName.Descendants("Product_Key")
           let name = product.Attribute("Name")            
           let keys = product.Elements("Key")
           select new MsProduct
           {
               Name = (string)name,
               Type = keys.First().Attribute("Type").Value,
               Key = (List<string>)keys.Select(x=>x.Value).ToList()
           };
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. This solved the problem I had with the list of keys, but my `type`is still empty.I change it to : 
let type = productName.Descendants("Key").Attributes("Type")

Type = (string)type.Select(x=> x.Value).ToString(),

But now, the value of `Type` is 
"
Type "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute,System.String]" string
"

Comment: What do you want to see as a type ?  "Static Activation Key" for example ?

Comment: yes, I have static activation key, retail or MultipleActivation in the file and I need this information for my software.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need those `let` statements. You do need to get the values form your keys.

```
var list = from product in productName.Descendants("Product_Key")
               where product.Attribute("Name").Value == "YourKey"
             //  let name = product.Attribute("Name")
             //  let type = product.Attribute("Type")
             //  let keys = product.Elements("Key")
               select new MsProduct
               {
                   Name = (string)product.Attribute("Name"),
                   Type = product.Elements("Type").First().Attribute("Type").Value,
                   Key = product.Elements("Key").Select(e=>e.Value).ToList()
               };
```

But `Elements("Type").First()` is of course a questionable definition.
There is no such thing as *the* Type of a ProductKey. It can have many Types.

Comment: It does indeed solve the problem for my "type" issue. Thank you very much!!!! Do you mind me asking why it's a questionable definition?

Comment: Because the XML clearly allows different Types for one Product_Key. So saying _the_ Type here is getting the cardinalities wrong.